# Обработчик формы

Tags: php

Можете помочь написать обработчик? "введено ли в поле, если да, то выполняем, а если нет, то выдаем ошибку."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот файл 1.php

```
<?php
if($_POST['var']!=null){
// тут что-то выполняется...
}else{
exit("ошибка");
}
?>
```

вот форма в 1.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="1.php">
<input type="text" name="var">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А если у меня например в форме 2 поля, то как скрипт записать? 

 ` <?php
if($_POST['var1']!=null){
// тут что-то выполняется...
}else{
exit("ошибка");
}
if($_POST['var2']!=null){
// тут что-то выполняется...
}else{
exit("ошибка");
}
?> `

Так?

Comment: Можно и так. Проследите за логикой скрипта:
Если var1 не Null (то есть в переменной что-то есть) то происходит выполнение куска "// тут что-то выполняется...",

Если var1 пустая — то выводится "ошибка" и дальше скрипт не выполняется, соответственно второй блок с IF даже не будет обработан.

Есть вот такой вариант:
<pre>
<?php
if($_POST['var1']!=null AND $_POST['var2']!=null){
// тут что-то выполняется...
}else{
exit("Обе переменные пустые");
}
?>
</pre>

Answer (score 2):

php

```
<?php
/* Осуществляем проверку вводимых данных и их защиту от враждебных скриптов */
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]);
$phone = htmlspecialchars($_POST["phone"]);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]);

/* Устанавливаем e-mail адресата */
$myemail = "Ваше мыло";

/* Проверяем заполнены ли обязательные поля ввода, используя check_input функцию */
$name = check_input($_POST["name"], "<center><b><span style='color:red; font: 15px Arial';>Введите ваше имя!</span><p>");
$phone = check_input($_POST["phone"], "<center><b><span style='color:red; font: 15px Arial';>Вы забыли написать номер телефона!</span><p>");
$email = check_input($_POST["email"], "<center><b><span style='color:red; font: 15px Arial';>Введите ваше имя!</span><p>");

/* Проверяем правильно ли записано имя */
if (!preg_match("/^[a-z а-яё 0-9]{2,30}$/iu", $name))
{
show_error("<br><center><b><span style='color:red; font: 15px Arial';> Убедитесь что Имя содержит от 2 до 30 символов</span><p>");
}

/* Проверяем правильно ли записан e-mail */
if (!preg_match( '#^[0-9a-z_\-\.]+@[0-9a-z\-\.]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$#i', $email))
{
show_error("<br><center><b><span style='color:red; font: 15px Arial';> Пожалуйста, введите корректный адресс электронной почты. E-mail должен иметь вид: <span style='color:blue';>user@somehost.com</span></span><p>");
}
/* Проверяем правильно ли записан номер телефона пользователя*/
if (!preg_match( '/[0-9]{5,15}/', $phone))
{
show_error("<br><center><b><span style='color:red; font: 15px Arial';> Не правильно заполнено поле номер телефона. Номер телефона: <span style='color:blue';> 8 063 077 00 00(без пробелов)</span></span><p>");
}

$to = "Ваше мыло"; 
$subject = "Сообщение от посетителя сайта";
$message = "\nИмя:$name  \nТелефон:$phone \nПочта:$email"; 
mail ($to,$subject,$message, "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 \r\n") or print "Не могу отправить сообщение.";
?>

<?php
/* Если при заполнении формы были допущены ошибки сработает следующий код: */
function check_input($data, $problem = "")
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}
function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
<body>
<p><center><b><span style='color:red; font: 15px Arial';>Пожалуйста, исправьте следующую ошибку:</span></p>
<?php echo $myError; 
{
echo "<a href=../index.html#form> Вернуться и правильно заполнить форму.</a>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

html

```
<form id="form" action="php/form.php" method="post" >

<div><input type="text"  name="name" placeholder="ВАШЕ ИМЯ" /></div>                    
<div><input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="ВАШ ТЕЛЕФОН"/></div>                      
<div><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="ВАШ E-MAIL"/></div>                       
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="ЗАКАЗАТЬ"/>              
</form>
```